# Unable to write contents of file

Tags: java, io, printwriter

```
package employee;

import employee.nidhin.staples;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 



public class Employee {


public static void main(String[] args) 

{
   int j=3;
   staples[] stemp = new staples[j];
  String file_name = "d:/personal/11636470/NetBeansProjects/Employee/src/employee/Xanadu.txt";


 try

 {

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

 for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            stemp[j] = new staples();

            System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
            stemp[j].setName(reader.readLine());

            System.out.println("Enter your age : "); 
            stemp[j].setAge(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));


        }


 for ( j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Employee number:" + j +" name:"+stemp[j].getName()+" Age:"+stemp[j].getAge() );

        }




 reader.close(); // VERY IMPORTANT TO CLOSE 

 System.out.println("Now writing the file to Xanadu.txt "); 

  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
  new FileWriter("file_name"));
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
       out.println("Value at: "+ i + " = "+ stemp[i].getName());
  }

  System.out.println("Successfully wrote to file");

  out.close();


 }
 catch(java.io.IOException ex)
 {
     System.out.println("Error is " + ex.getMessage() ); 
 }



}   
}
```

The program execute successfully , but when I open the outputfile Xanadu.txt , I see nothing. Can someone guide me? The contents of the file Xanadu.txt is an array of objects stemp which have two attributes name and age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file_name"));
```

You're passing a String that says: "file_name",
try doing that:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(file_name)));
```

I think it should work. As FileWriter constructor should take File as a parameter, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There must not be quotation marks around `file_name`. If you put them around, it is interpreted as a string, and the data is written to a file called "file_name" in the working dir.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
new FileWriter(file_name));
```

...would be correct

Answer (score 0):

Best way is just make it simple: try below code :

```
fos=new File(filepath);
if(fos.exists() && fos.isFile() && !fos.isDirectory())
{
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fos);
    BufferedWriter Bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);
    Bw.append("i am appending text to the existing file");
}
```

if you want to write by creating new file then go for file searching first and if does not exist then create and write data in same using below:

```
fos=new File(filepath);
if(!fos.exists() && !fos.isFile())
{
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fos);  
    BufferedWriter Bw= new BufferedWriter(fw);
    Bw.write("i am writing text to the existing file");
}
```

Comment: just missed a line in second code snippet: fos.createNewFile();

Comment: You are not appending to any file here; `fos.isFile()` implies `!fos.isDirectory()`; in the second example the `if` statement is redundant; merely adding `true` for the `append` parameter of `new FileWriter` would make *both* if statements and the entire second bck redundant; `fos` is a stupid name for a variable of type `File`; and none of this answers the actual question in any way.